# I'm trying to pass data to this form but I'm keep getting the same error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'persist')

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (edit) {
      console.log(item)
      setValues(item!);
    } 
    document.body.style.overflow = showModal ? "hidden" : "";
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [edit, showModal]);
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      id: null as string | number | null,
      brandDescription: "",
      brandShortDescription: "",
      imagePath: null as string | number | null,
      statusDescription: false,
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({}),
    onSubmit: async (values, helpers) => {
      const filteredValue = {
        codigoMarca: values?.id,
        descripcionMarca: values?.brandDescription,
        estatus: values?.statusDescription ? 'A' : 'C',
        descripcionCortaMarca: values?.brandShortDescription,
      };
      await request(filteredValue)
      helpers.resetForm();
      handleModal();
    },
  });

  const setValues = (values: BrandsFront | undefined) => {
   const newValue = {
      id: values!.id,
      brandDescription: values!.brandDescription,
      brandShortDescription: values!.brandShortDescription,
      imagePath: '',
      statusDescription: values!.statusDescription === "Activo" ? true : false,
    };
    formik.setValues(newValue); 
  };
```

```
<Autocomplete
  id="asynchronous-brands"
  isOptionEqualToValue={(opt, value) => opt.id === value.id}
  value={formik.values.brandDescription}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
  options={brands}
  onInputChange={formik.handleChange}
  onChange={formik.handleChange}
  inputValue={formik.values.brandDescription}
  renderInput={(params) => (
   <TextField
     sx={{-- styles --}}
     {...params}
     placeholder="Descripción de Marca"
    />
   )}
  size="small"
 />
```

I know that the main problem is the Autocomplete component from material UI, I've tried to add/remove/modify the props, but it kept giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

the error message indicate you cant access to property of null object , in this case the property is called persist, but in your publish code  i dont see was this property is called, but this error can be solved with operator "?" object?.persist
you can see more information in this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: instead of blindly suggesting a solution, try ask the OP more information about their problem, so you can give them a correct answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).